# Could not find stored procedure dbo aspnet CheckSchemaVersion LOCAL HOST

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, authentication, membership-provider

I search this question in site but my problem has little differences.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with c#-asp.net

Everything was going well so far but suddenly login and register crashed.

The program can connect to database. I can do other things for example inserting a data to database or delete it but just login and register crashed.

I do not think I deleted something.

I am not using server it is local host.

--

How can i fix it?

the error is

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +2073502
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064460
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +215
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +987
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +178
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   System.Web.Util.SecUtility.CheckSchemaVersion(ProviderBase provider, SqlConnection connection, String[] features, String version, Int32& schemaVersionCheck) +392
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckSchemaVersion(SqlConnection connection) +84
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +827
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +106
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +60
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +129
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +127
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `aspnet_regsql` from the Visual Studio Command Prompt to re-create the database stuff used by the built-in membership system.

Comment: that is not working. when I choose database I got that error
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/26/hataaaaa.png/

Comment: i tried .\SQLExpress but failed. unable to connect dba

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/40/hataa2.png/

Comment: Use whatever connection string you're using in the site.

Comment: Failed again. Thank you for everything but it is better to start a new project :(

Answer (score 1):

did you check ..if you can see the same stored procedure in sqlserver/oracle database login directly there (whatever using it) . it might be possible that you executed in difernet schema and now its not able to find it .

Answer (score 0):

Call [`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.initializedatabaseconnection%28VS.111%29.aspx), and you shall be good.

If you're created your project as VS2012 web app, just delete the `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute`, instead do the initialization at `Application_Start` or in another location on demand.